# Thread count discrepancy in Overall Active Thread graph

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using JMeter-2.13. I have two Thread Groups in test plan. One group contributes 20 threads and other contributes 50 threads.

[image: Individual Thread Groups]

In Overall Active Threads graph, I see dips in thread count on the graph line. I don't see such dips in individual graph then why do they appear in Overall Active Threads graph -

[image: Overall Active Thread Groups]

Comment: The way I expect it works is it displays the same data that is displayed in JMeter CSV output. If there is a delay in transfering results from remote JMeter instance, I wouldn't be surprised there are some drops.

Does it happen when you monitor execution results as you go, or also after you load run results of non-gui mode?

Comment: I am loading the test result from GUI.
What surprises is why I don't see drops on individual thread groups but only when I plot "Overall Active Thread"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first graph you are seeing results of 2 thread groups and in second graph for individual group.

These plugins are developed by Loadosohpia/Blazemeter team and when I asked them about this. They provided following reasoning for this behavior..

> Loadosophia does interpolation of points by averaging every N points
>   into single point. So if you have spike surrounded by zero values,
>   they will affect the spike height. Sorry, we can't have infinite
>   precision on graph.